# Display monthly columns by year using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to graph the global surface temperature as a time-series, and am using NASA GISS data. The data is organised by year, month, and season.

I want to display it as a timeseries from Jan 1880 to Feb 2016, showing each monthly value.

Read in the data and code NA values

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("http://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/tabledata_v3/GLB.Ts+dSST.csv",
na_values = ["**** ","***  "])
```

Select necessary data

```
df = data.ix[:,1:19]
```

Add a year Column

```
df['Year'] = data[' Year']
```

I've tried making a pivot table sorted by year but this just reproduces the original data-frame.

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index = df['Year'], values=['Jan','Feb', 'Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'])
```

I want the dataframe to have one column of data values indexed by year, with 12 values for each month in each year, I thought the pivot table would do this but I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) with [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) column `Year`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("http://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/tabledata_v3/GLB.Ts+dSST.csv",
na_values = ["**** ","***  "])
print data.head()

df1 = pd.melt(data, id_vars=[' Year'], value_vars=['Jan','Feb', 'Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'], var_name='Month').rename(columns={' Year':'Year'})

print df1.columns
Index([u'Year', u'Month', u'value'], dtype='object')

print df1
```

```
       Year Month  value
0      1880   Jan    -29
1      1881   Jan     -9
2      1882   Jan     10
3      1883   Jan    -33
4      1884   Jan    -17
5      1885   Jan    -63
6      1886   Jan    -40
7      1887   Jan    -64
8      1888   Jan    -42
9      1889   Jan    -18
10     1890   Jan    -46
11     1891   Jan    -44
12     1892   Jan    -25
13     1893   Jan    -66
14     1894   Jan    -53
15     1895   Jan    -42
16     1896   Jan    -22
17     1897   Jan    -21
18     1898   Jan     -5
19     1899   Jan    -16
20     1900   Jan    -38
21     1901   Jan    -28
22     1902   Jan    -18
23     1903   Jan    -26
24     1904   Jan    -63
25     1905   Jan    -36
26     1906   Jan    -29
27     1907   Jan    -42
28     1908   Jan    -44
29     1909   Jan    -69
...     ...   ...    ...
1614   1987   Dec     48
1615   1988   Dec     33
1616   1989   Dec     36
1617   1990   Dec     41
1618   1991   Dec     32
1619   1992   Dec     22
1620   1993   Dec     19
1621   1994   Dec     36
1622   1995   Dec     30
1623   1996   Dec     40
1624   1997   Dec     59
1625   1998   Dec     57
1626   1999   Dec     47
1627   2000   Dec     30
1628   2001   Dec     54
1629   2002   Dec     42
1630   2003   Dec     73
1631   2004   Dec     51
1632   2005   Dec     67
1633   2006   Dec     78
1634   2007   Dec     49
1635   2008   Dec     54
1636   2009   Dec     64
1637   2010   Dec     48
1638   2011   Dec     53
1639   2012   Dec     52
1640   2013   Dec     66
1641   2014   Dec     79
1642   2015   Dec    110
1643   2016   Dec    NaN

[1644 rows x 3 columns]
```

Then you can create new `Datetimeindex` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1['Year'].astype(str) + df1['Month'], format='%Y%b')
timeserie = df1['value'].head()
print timeserie.head()
1880-01-01 00:00:00   -29
1881-01-01 00:00:00    -9
1882-01-01 00:00:00    10
1883-01-01 00:00:00   -33
1884-01-01 00:00:00   -17
Name: value, dtype: float64

print df1.index
DatetimeIndex(['1880-01-01', '1881-01-01', '1882-01-01', '1883-01-01',
               '1884-01-01', '1885-01-01', '1886-01-01', '1887-01-01',
               '1888-01-01', '1889-01-01',
               ...
               '2007-12-01', '2008-12-01', '2009-12-01', '2010-12-01',
               '2011-12-01', '2012-12-01', '2013-12-01', '2014-12-01',
               '2015-12-01', '2016-12-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=1644, freq=None)
```

Or if you need `PeriodIndex`, use [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html):

```
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1['Year'].astype(str) + df1['Month'], format='%Y%b')
df1.index = df1.index.to_period('M')
timeserie = df1['value'].head()
print timeserie.head()
1880-01   -29
1881-01    -9
1882-01    10
1883-01   -33
1884-01   -17
Freq: M, Name: value, dtype: float64

print df1.index
PeriodIndex(['1880-01', '1881-01', '1882-01', '1883-01', '1884-01', '1885-01',
             '1886-01', '1887-01', '1888-01', '1889-01',
             ...
             '2007-12', '2008-12', '2009-12', '2010-12', '2011-12', '2012-12',
             '2013-12', '2014-12', '2015-12', '2016-12'],
            dtype='int64', length=1644, freq='M')
```

Or you can first select `df` with columns `Year` and months by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) and then use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html).
Last you can add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with seting column `names`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("http://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/tabledata_v3/GLB.Ts+dSST.csv",
na_values = ["**** ","***  "])
print data.head()

df = data.ix[:,0:13] 

print df.columns
Index([u' Year', u'Jan', u'Feb', u'Mar', u'Apr', u'May', u'Jun', u'Jul',
       u'Aug', u'Sep', u'Oct', u'Nov', u'Dec'],
      dtype='object')

table = df.set_index(' Year').stack().reset_index()
table.columns = ['Year','Month','Value']
```

```
print table
      Year Month  Value
0     1880   Jan    -29
1     1880   Feb    -20
2     1880   Mar    -18
3     1880   Apr    -27
4     1880   May    -14
5     1880   Jun    -28
6     1880   Jul    -23
7     1880   Aug     -7
8     1880   Sep    -16
9     1880   Oct    -16
10    1880   Nov    -18
11    1880   Dec    -21
12    1881   Jan     -9
13    1881   Feb    -13
14    1881   Mar      1
15    1881   Apr     -3
16    1881   May     -4
17    1881   Jun    -28
18    1881   Jul     -6
19    1881   Aug     -2
20    1881   Sep     -8
21    1881   Oct    -19
22    1881   Nov    -26
23    1881   Dec    -15
24    1882   Jan     10
25    1882   Feb      9
26    1882   Mar      2
27    1882   Apr    -20
28    1882   May    -17
29    1882   Jun    -25
...    ...   ...    ...
1604  2013   Sep     76
1605  2013   Oct     69
1606  2013   Nov     80
1607  2013   Dec     66
1608  2014   Jan     73
1609  2014   Feb     50
1610  2014   Mar     77
1611  2014   Apr     78
1612  2014   May     86
1613  2014   Jun     66
1614  2014   Jul     58
1615  2014   Aug     81
1616  2014   Sep     90
1617  2014   Oct     85
1618  2014   Nov     68
1619  2014   Dec     79
1620  2015   Jan     81
1621  2015   Feb     87
1622  2015   Mar     90
1623  2015   Apr     73
1624  2015   May     78
1625  2015   Jun     78
1626  2015   Jul     73
1627  2015   Aug     78
1628  2015   Sep     82
1629  2015   Oct    106
1630  2015   Nov    103
1631  2015   Dec    110
1632  2016   Jan    114
1633  2016   Feb    135

[1634 rows x 3 columns]
```